# Loop for multiple select statements

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am a bit confused on how to deal with looping on multiple select statements using PL/SQL for PostgreSQL. I have written a function that works as expected for multiple select statements that each return a single row (see code below). 
I have a middle table (called bridge_table) that breaks up many-to-many relationship between tables 'stock' and 'client', where one client_id can match up with multiple stock_id.

How/Where do I add in the necessary LOOP syntax to grab all the necessary stock_id's for a client_id? Is this a scenario where a cursor might be useful?

Thanks ahead of time!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(
    a_id INTEGER,
    b_id INTEGER,
    c_id INTEGER)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE
    current_time TIMESTAMP;
    new_inv INTEGER;
    inv_id INTEGER;
    inv_q INTEGER;
    current_quant INTEGER;
    still_true boolean := true;
BEGIN
    current_time := clock_timestamp();

    SELECT i_id INTO inv_id
    FROM bridge_table
    WHERE bridge_table.client_id=c_id;

    SELECT inv_quant INTO inv_q
    FROM bridge_table
    WHERE bridge_table.client_id=c_id;

    SELECT quantity INTO current_quant
    FROM stock
    WHERE stock.i_id=inv_id;


    IF current_quant < inv_q THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'STOP';
        still_true := false;
    ELSE
        new_inv := current_quant - inv_q;

    UPDATE stock
        SET quantity = new_inv
        WHERE i_id=inv_id;
    END IF;

    IF still_true = true THEN
        INSERT INTO log_table (log_id, u_id, client_id, time)
        VALUES (a_id, b_id, c_id, current_time);    
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'TRANSACTION WILL NOT OCCUR';
    END IF;

    RETURN still_true;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Edit:
Table DDLs

```
CREATE TABLE stock
(
    i_id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name          VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    quantity      INTEGER      NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE clients
(
    client_id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE bridge_table
(
    client_id    INTEGER REFERENCES clients (client_id),
    i_id         INTEGER REFERENCES stock (i_id),
    inv_quant    INTEGER NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE log
(
    log_id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    u_id         INTEGER   REFERENCES users (user_id),
    client_id    INTEGER REFERENCES clients (client_id),
    time         TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Is this for Oracle?

Comment: Please provide table DDL and sample data, as text, and the expected results for that. It wouldn't hurt to review [ask]. Also you indicated you were after all stock for a client but do want this for a specified client or all clients?

Comment: This is for PostgreSql. Added the DDLs as well. I would like all the stock for a specified client.